Does the "Narayanam Namaskritya" verse appear in multiple scriptures?
This
https://narayanpedia.com/narayanam-namaskritya-shlok-meaning/
website says so:

नारायणं नमस्कृत्य नरं चैव नरोत्तमम्।
देवीं सरस्वतीं व्यासं ततो जयमुदीरयेत्।
naaraayanam namaskri’tya naram chaiva narottamam. deveem sarasvateem vyaasam tato jayamudeerayet.


This shloka appears at the beginning of the Puranas and also at several places in Mahabharata. Let us look at the meaning of this shloka.


It says – before narrating Jaya, you should offer Namaskaras to Narayana, Nara-Narayana, Saraswati Devi, and Vyasa. Jaya means the Puranas, and Mahabharata.


Also in Srimad Bhagavatam - https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/1/2/4/

Yes. It does appear in multiple scriptures.

In Padma Purana, this verse is appearing in the first chapter of
Uttara Khanda.


Padma Purana 6.1.1
Om, salutation to Śrī Viṣṇu. Om salutation to Śrī Vedavyāsa.Om, having
saluted Nārāyaṇa, so also Nara, the best among men, and goddess
Sarasvatī and Vyāsa, one should narrate the (god’s) glory.


In Skanda Purana, it appears in first chapter of Ayodhya
Mahatmiya of Vaishnava Khanda. It also appears as the last part of the very first verse of the Purana.
In Brahma Vaivarta Purana it appears in the very first verse of
Brahma Khanda.
In Srimad Bhagavatam it appears in the 4th verse of second chapter of first canto.

Will update the answer once I found more.
